# Website fingerprinting based on packet traces

Tags: web-browser, packet, fingerprint

Given a set of traces coming from different websites, where each trace is a packet. Assume we only know the time of arrival, size and direction of each packet. How do we go about fingerprinting these traces to a particular website?

I am looking for how to derive a fingerprint for a website based on only the three pieces of information provided (i.e. time of arrival, size and direction of packet traces). And then potentially match these traces if they have the same fingerprint.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused. Is there anything specific you're looking for or the question is to explain in general how a website fingerprinting works?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.

I am looking for how to derive a fingerprint for a website based on only the three information provided (i.e. time of arrival, size and direction of packet traces). And then potentially match these traces if they have the same fingerprint.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the relevant research? (e.g. *https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-15497-3_13.pdf*, *https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~salinisk/642/website_fingerprinting_paper.pdf* and *http://infolab.stanford.edu/~qsun/research/identification.pdf*)

Comment: Will simply comparing size of packets and direction give a reasonable match between fingerprints? 

For example, based on a set of traces from two URLs, compare the number of exact matches in packet size/direction. If the number of matches are reasonably high, then we can infer that both traces are from the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

Question is too vague and generic, title is about website fingerprinting (which is L7 concept), but you talk about network packets, which are L3-L4 concept.

Because of that it is impossible, you either need to do L4 fingerprinting (TCP/IP stack fingerprinting) or L7 fingerprinting (SSL JA3 fingerprinting, or HTML5 Canvas fingerprinting)

Comment: Website fingerprinting (WF) can refer to the act of passively monitoring network packets in order to find out which website a user visits, in the case where the user utilizes privacy-enhancing methods to access the website, like Tor (see for example this paper *https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity22/presentation/cherubin* and this paper *https://journalofcloudcomputing.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13677-021-00244-8*)